# Define a custom DbConnectionFactory for encrypt connection strings and set it as DefaultConnectionFactory in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, customization, dbconnectionfactory

I have a `BaseDbContext` in my solution that all other `DbContexts` inherited from it:

```
public BaseDbContext(string connectionstringName): base(connectionstringName)
{
  ....
}
```

Recently I added following `DbConnectionFactory` to decrypt my encrypted `connectionstring` in my config file(I encrypted the config file once):

```
public class EncryptedDbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory
{
   public EncryptedDbConnectionFactory()
   {
   }

   #region IDbConnectionFactory implementation
   public DbConnection CreateConnection(string nameOrConnectionString)
   {
      var connectionStringName = nameOrConnectionString.Replace("name=","");

      //Decrypt method get connectionstringName, and find connectionstring   from config 
      //and decrypt it

      var decryptedConnectionString = Decrypt(connectionStringName);
      var connection= new SqlConnection(decryptedConnectionString);
      return connection;
   }
   #endregion
}
```

and set it as `DefaultConnectionFactory` by following `DbConfiguration` class:

```
public class MyConfig : DbConfiguration
{
   public UseConnectionStringsConfig(bool useEncryptedDbConnectionFactory)
   {
     if (useEncryptedDbConnectionFactory)
     {
       SetProviderServices("System.Data.SqlClient",
                            System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.Instance);
       SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new EncryptedDbConnectionFactory(configuration));
     }
     else
     {
        //use sqlConnectionFactory
     }
   }
}
```

and call `MyConfig` in beginning of my `program.cs`(I removed `defaultConnectionFactory` section from my `app.config` too):

```
DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MyConfig(true));
```

when I run the program, I get following exception when control reachs to `var context = new MyContext();` line:

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

if I change my `BaseDbContext` to:

```
public BaseDbContext(string connectionstringName)
      : base(Database.DefaultConnectionFactory
                     .CreateConnection(connectionstringName), true)
{
}
```

the program run without any exception; but by using `Database.DefaultConnectionFactory` as `DbContext` constructor's parameter, I get following warning:

> 'Database.DefaultConnectionFactory' is obsolete: 'The default connection factory should be set in the config file or using the DbConfiguration class. (See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883)

I have 2 questions:

1. How can I fix this warning?(I mean that how can I fix the problem by better way than use `Database.DefaultConnectionFactory` as `DbContext` constructor's parameter )
2. Why my earlier `BaseDbContext` does not work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I. The warning explains that. You should not use `Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new EncryptedDbConnectionFactory(true)`. Insted you should set it in configuration file:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="YourNamespace.EncryptedDbConnectionFactory, YourAssembly">
      <parameters>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      ........
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

II. The reason of exception is that the connection string is not in correct format. Check your decrypting method and see if your final connection string is in correct format.

Comment: 1) I set defaultConnectionFactory in my config file, but the problem does not fix, I get the same exception, yet.  2)the decrypted connection string is correct, but in `BaseDbContext` the `Database.Connection.ConnectionString` is Empty (""), I put `var c = this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;` in `BaseDbcontext`'s constructor to check it.

Comment: @Masoud, have a look at [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699). This may help you.